# Cumulative probability of increasing probability for game fail stacking

Tags: probability-theory

In regards to [Cumulative probability of increasing probability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2605196/cumulative-probability-of-increasing-probability/2605212#2605212)

Hello, sorry for digging up a grave post. I've been trying to wrap my head around this. Could you answer a few questions?

First, is this a Binomial Distribution problem?

Second, If I was doing some equipment upgrading, where every fail gives a % increase ( eg fail stacking) how would this work?

Third, Do you have an excel friendly formula? I've been trying to use BINOM.DIST on google sheet, and I believe it works with a non increasing %.

Thank you kindly and stay safe.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, if you have a chance of 3% to happen, the question 'How likely is it that after 20 trials it has not occurred even once?' is a question where the binomial distribution will give the correct result. In particular, you are looking for $P(X=0)$ for $X\sim B(0.03,20)$.
2. There are various ways to think about this. First of all, in the video game context designers will often 'cheat' and not actually implement the stated probabilities, because humans are terrible at accepting true randomness as random. Even if you have just a few hundred players in a coin-flipping game one of them will get 10 Heads or Tails in a row, which will make their personal experience different from what the developer might have intended.

What you can do however is just multiply the success chance by a factor or just add something, in both cases with a cutoff of 1 since probabilities cannot be bigger than 1.
So if your starting probability is $p_0$ and you want to increase the probability by $q$ then you might just set $p_1=p_0+q$ or $p_1=p_0(1+q)$ (these approaches will need different values of $q$ of course, they are not at all equivalent). There are smoother ways to increase probabilities without ever going over $1$ but that does not seem to be what you are looking for.
This would mean that you are having a different distribution after every additional failure. You can model this via Markov Chains, for example, they are nice and visual.

3. I might be wrong but if you want the distribution of your events to depend on the previous events then I think it will be very hard to model this in a single excel cell. If you want to get some simulated data for various implementations I would not use a spreadsheet but whatever programming language you find most approachable.

Comment: Thank you so much! That helped a lot!